# Disable wifi in source code

Tags: java, android

In android source code 'WifiEnabler.java' class I want to disable wifi when battery voltage is below 3.4. I am getting battery voltage but i am unable to disable toggle button. How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: post your code for wifi enabler

Answer (score 0):

you didn't mention your way to enable wifi with WifiEnabler.java but for disabled wifi you can use

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

__

As source code you mention is this? http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.1_r2/com/android/settings/wifi/WifiEnabler.java

then you can call to

```
setWifiEnabled(false);
```

Comment: where is wifi enabling in WifiEnabler.java class?

Comment: I modified answer you can call to  setWifiEnabled(false); in WifiEnabler.java

Comment: Ya the link is correct but where i have to disable where is the piece of code to disable?

Comment: in source : 104    private void setWifiEnabled(final boolean enable) {

Comment: I am usinh this code "http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/settings/wifi/WifiEnabler.java/"

Comment: have u seen my comment?? I am using the source code of above link

Comment: you could add this method inside WifiEnabler

     public WifiDisabler(Context context, Switch switch_) {
         mContext = context;
         mSwitch = switch_;
 
         mWifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
         mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
     }

Answer (score 0):

First Add:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission> 
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

to the manifest file.

Then you can enable/disable  WiFi using [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) class as:

```
 WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE); 

    if (wm.isWifiEnabled()) { 
       wm.setWifiEnabled(false);
    }
    else{ 
       wm.setWifiEnabled(true); 
    }
```